# Return values for X and Y where X-Y = Max(X-Y)

Tags: t-sql, aggregation

(SQL SERVER 2005)

I have a table of multiple products that relate to an ItemCode. I can establish the best saving using the query below (I think) but what I need to include are the RRP and SellingPrice fields for the combination that provides the best saving.

Apologies in advance this is probably a common issue but I can't find a solution that fits.

```
SELECT     ItemCode, MAX(RRP - [SellingPrice]) AS BestSaving
       FROM          ItemCodePricingDetail
       WHERE      ([ProductGroup] = N'SHOES') AND ([Stock Flag] = N'Y') 
                 AND (RRP > 0) AND ([SellingPrice] > 0)
       GROUP BY ItemCode
```

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select * from ItemCodePricingDetail
JOIN
(
SELECT     ItemCode, MAX(RRP - [SellingPrice]) AS BestSaving
       FROM          ItemCodePricingDetail
       WHERE      ([ProductGroup] = N'SHOES') AND ([Stock Flag] = N'Y') 
                 AND (RRP > 0) AND ([SellingPrice] > 0)
       GROUP BY ItemCode
) as t1  on ItemCodePricingDetail.ItemCode=t1.ItemCode 
            and RRP - [SellingPrice]= t1.BestSaving
```

Comment: Very nice. I didn't know you could join like "RRP - [SellingPrice]= t1.BestSaving"